# Convert a list to another list in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I recall seeing something like this in the documentation before, but I can't find it right now.

I have a list of instances I have created `aws_instance.managers.*.id` what I want to do is convert it to another list suitable for cloudwatch dashboard which looks like

```
  [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      "i-0f2",
  ],
```

So say I have a list `aws_instance.managers.*.id` which resolves to `["i-a", "i-b", "i-c"]`  I want it to transform into something like

```
[
  [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      "i-a",
  ],
  [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      "i-b",
  ],
  [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      "i-c",
  ],
]
```

Presumably something like

```
locals {
  dashboard_cpu_balance = [ foreach aws_instance.managers.*.id => 
    [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      "i-a",
    ],
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this....

```
locals {
  dashboard_cpu_balance = [ for a in aws_instance.managers.*.id :
    [
      ".",
      "CPUCreditBalance",
      ".",
      a,
    ]
  ]
}
```

Output..

```
Outputs:

op = [
  [
    ".",
    "CPUCreditBalance",
    ".",
    "i-a",
  ],
  [
    ".",
    "CPUCreditBalance",
    ".",
    "i-b",
  ],
  [
    ".",
    "CPUCreditBalance",
    ".",
    "i-c",
  ],
]
```

Comment: Can you add the link where it is documented?

Comment: For Expressions are documented here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions